# Save the grid content to db based on the selected header (dropdown)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have bound a dynamic `DropDown` at the header content of the `Grid` . The `DropDown` is nothing but containing the column names of a table(The number of columns are changeable).
If the `DDL` is selected , I should be able to save the column content as a whole to the respective table.

I tried this below code, but **this will not achieve my specification**

```
string StrQuery;
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
        {
            comm.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            for(int i=0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
                StrQuery= @"INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (" 
                    + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value +", " 
                    + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value +");";
                comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Please understand the question.**

now i want to save the resultant grid based on the header selection to the database

How do I do this??

Is there any easier way to achieve this?

Comment: I think that you have to loop through grid view items and insert it one by one as you have done

Comment: Did you set the property `AutoPostBack=true` of that dropdown ?

Comment: What did you get in error?

Answer (score 1):

You missed single quote `'` around `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells` values. It should be like this:

```
StrQuery= @"INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('" 
            + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value +"', '" 
            + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value +"');";
```

Although I strongly recommend that you always use [`parameterized queries`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
StrQuery= @"INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (@col1, @col2)";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col2", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value);
```